# This command is not available because no document is open C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, xps

I am Generating XPS document from Word document recursively but I am getting the error below:

**Error:**

> This command is not available because no document is open. at Miscrosoft.office.interop.Word.ApplicationClass.get_ActiveDo‌​cument at Line 65

which is:

```cs
wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(xpsFile, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
```

I am using the Following Code to convert the **Word Files to XPS files**

```cs
public static string convertWordToXps(string path, string wordDocName)
{
    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
    wordApp.Documents.Open(string.Concat(path, "\\", wordDocName), ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: false);

    string xpsFile = string.Concat(path, "\\", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordDocName), ".xps");

    try
    {
        //wordApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(xpsFileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatXPS, false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, false, true, WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, false, true, false, nullObject);
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(xpsFile, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
        return xpsFile;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.getDetailedErrorMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        wordApp.Quit(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: Type.Missing, RouteDocument: Type.Missing);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Search Function**

```cs
private void SearchDocuments(string directoryPath)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string fullName in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.odt"))
        {
            InstructionsViewModel.convertWordToXps(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullName), System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullName));
        }
        foreach (string nestedDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath))
        {
            SearchDocuments(nestedDirectory);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception error)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to convert all the Word files to XPS inside all the folders.

Comment: Side note: use [Path.Combine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0) instead of string concatenation. It takes care of removing extra backslashes or adding missing ones.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks for the suggestion but this is not the problem here

Comment: @Muhammadzubair before saving try to activate your document: 
`wordApp.Documents(wordDocName"+".extension_of_doc").Activate()`
You open document only, but it isnt active.

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik can you post your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving try to activate your document

```
wordApplication= new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var document= wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"path/to/document.docx");  
document.Activate();
// and now save.
```

In your code it would look like:

```
public static string convertWordToXps(string path, string wordDocName)
{
    Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
    var document= wordApp.Documents.Open(string.Concat(path, "\\", wordDocName), ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: false);
    document.Activate();
    string xpsFile = string.Concat(path, "\\", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordDocName), ".xps");

    try
    {
        //wordApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(xpsFileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatXPS, false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, false, true, WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, false, true, false, nullObject);
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(xpsFile, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
        return xpsFile;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.getDetailedErrorMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        wordApp.Quit(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: Type.Missing, RouteDocument: Type.Missing);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Non Invokable member '_Applcation.Documents' cannot be used like method

Comment: @Muhammadzubair try now. Its because `Documents` is a list and you have to find the specific document that you want to activate. Either by giving name or index.
Updated my code, please try again.

Comment: Actually i don't want to convert the only one file. i want to convert all the "*.odt" files inside all the folders in the path which i am providing.  

Path is like this : Z:\Instructions. and inside instructions there are other folders and in side each folder there are "*.odt" files which i want to convert to XPS    

The above line i changed and there is no error but it is not converting i don't know why

Comment: @Muhammadzubair: ok, i edited my answer. You can copy and paste that code instead your function and it should work with any document.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

document was null.
 i copied paste your function and i got the above Error

Comment: @Muhammadzubair can you stop in the debugger on the line that you are opening document, and add a line before opening:
`string pathToDocument=string.Concat(path, "\\", wordDocName);`
And tell me how the path looks like ?
Probably you build it wrong, and the path of the document not exist (thats why document is null).
After you get that path, you can paste it in windows explorator to see if the document will open.
If it doesnt open, then it doesnt exist, and you have to correct the path.
You can also paste it here- i will try to guess what may be wrong.

Comment: i followed the steps which you have mentioned and i am getting the values of variables like 

pathToDocument = "Z:\\Instruktionen\\AV_143M6196_ USIPxs Grundlagen Pruefung_-" which is not there and path = Z:\\Instruktionen this one. we have problem with the \\ things as i Z:\\Instruktionen this is my local directory path but when i paste in windows explorer it is not opening because of two \\

Comment: in variable wordDocName : "AV_143M6196_ USIPxs Grundlagen Pruefung_-" i have this which is available at the main directory which means it is going inside the main Folder which is  Z:\Instructions 

But in document it is null :(

Comment: @Muhammadzubair specify extension if you want to load documents correctly.
What if there are 3 files:
AV_143M6196_ USIPxs Grundlagen Pruefung_-.txt
and
AV_143M6196_ USIPxs Grundlagen Pruefung_-.doc
and 
AV_143M6196_ USIPxs Grundlagen Pruefung_-.odt

How compiler should know which one to pick ?

Comment: extension is .odt i want to load .odt and convert it to xps files

Comment: @Muhammadzubair so add .odt to file name when opening document.

Comment: Finally it worked after adding .odt to file opening. You are simply Genius :)

Comment: managed debugging assistant 'disconnectedcontext' Got this error in the middle of the conversion of the files.

Comment: @Muhammadzubair im glad i could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the newly opened document is not yet active. But the `Open` method returns the document. So, no need to activate it or access it through an index or name.

```cs
Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(...);
doc.SaveAs2(...);
```

The whole method

```cs
public static string convertWordToXps(string path, string wordDocName)
{
    var wordApp = new Word.Application();
    Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(Path.Combine(path, wordDocName), ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: false);

    string xpsFile = Path.Combine(path, Path.ChangeExtension(wordDocName, ".xps"));

    try {
        doc.SaveAs2(xpsFile, FileFormat: Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);
        return xpsFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show(e.getDetailedErrorMessage());
    } finally {
        wordApp.Quit(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: Type.Missing, RouteDocument: Type.Missing);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Bit Confusing. what do i have to pass to doc.SaveAs2(...); ??? and where?

Comment: You did that already in your code. I did not mean to change the overall structure of your code, just suggested changes in two code lines. Fill in what you already have in the (...).

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  :( Not working

Comment: I cannot [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) your code. if `doc` is null, then probably it could not open the document.

Comment: Yes i did exactly the same and Yes doc is null.

Comment: Are the file paths on you local PC? Add the Test `if(!File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, wordDocName)) { throw new ArgumentExecption("The document does not exist"); }` before opening the document. Otherwise  Google for "word document open returns null".